# GWT how to allow the user to select PDF files to store in database

Tags: pdf, gwt

I am using IUploader to allow the user to select images which are then store in the database; however, this will not get pdf files. How do I get pdf files?

```
        // Create a new uploader panel and attach it to a document
        //final SingleUploader defaultUploader = new SingleUploader();
        defaultUploader.setAutoSubmit(true);
        defaultUploader.setEnabled(true);
        defaultUploader.avoidRepeatFiles(false);
        defaultUploader.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");

        // Add a finish handler which will load the image once the upload finishes
        defaultUploader.addOnFinishUploadHandler(onFinishUploaderHandler);
        defaultUploader.getFileInput().asWidget().setStyleName("customButton");
        defaultUploader.getFileInput().asWidget().setSize("90px", "20px");

        flexTable_Award.setWidget(2, 0, defaultUploader);
```

Comment: what happens whether you add this: defaultUploader..setValidExtensions(new String[]{"pdf"})?

Comment: Thank you, just tried it and no difference :-(

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being with displaying the pdf using an image widget. So I display the name instead. Your could also display a standard pdf image. If you want only pdf as the valid format then set the valid extension (defaultUploader.setValidExtensions("pdf");). If you want both images and pdf then you will need to test for the pdf and only display the image if it is not a pdf.